# Eating not right -gain muscles or no

Tags: muscle, workout, muscle-gain

Eating right has many advantages on our health and can help building muscles. On the other hand fast foods, sugar etc. are detrimental for gaining muscles. What is the reason for this? If a thin guy or normal body fat like me starts eating badly he will increase his body fat. As a result he will obtain obvious muscles faster than someone who is trying to eat healthy.

I'm talking about someone who eats fast food, etc. but takes protein meals in their program.

Will the guy who eats badly for a small period of time have a greater success than a guy who is eating healthy? Compare same workouts but different food. (For example three meals of beans versus three meals of fast food.)

Comment: *"he will obtain faster obvious muscles"* - I'd doubt that. He may get a bit bigger, but that's fat, not 'visible muscles'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL/DR:** Fast food should not be considered for bulking, there are better alternatives.

You have an issue with the categories you are thinking in. It's not only healthy vegetables vs. unhealthy fast-food.

First of all I'd doubt that fast-food will have any beneficial effect on the body. Of course, when working out, it's possible to gain some muscles when eating fast-food, but this is not because, but despite the fast food.

> [...] he will increase his body fat. As a result he will obtain obvious muscles faster than someone who is trying to eat healthy.

The person eating fast food will mostly gain fat, not muscles and therefor maybe look bigger, but this is not due to more muscles.

Having said that, eating healthy and gaining are not mutual exclusive, but you have to consider the following

- To bulk (gain weight - muscles at best) you have to be in a caloric surplus, i.e. take more calories than your body would normally need - at least on training days
- It *is* possible to eat healthy *and* be in a caloric surplus
- To gain muscles you have to take a considerable amount of protein (about 2 g per kg bodyweight)

  - There are many sources of good protein that are healthy (or at least not unhealthy): Lowfat quark, cottage cheese, chicken breast
  - You can supplement protein with whey and the like (look for quality products)
- Nuts and seeds have a high caloric density, but are considered quite healthy, opt for them if you need some extra calories
- Whole grain unsweetened cereals are great, too. Many fibers, still good source of calories.

Answer (score 1):

Just from the top of my head:

The main bad thing about fast food, it contains "bad" fat and "empty" sugar calories, is how it impacts in some ways  how your body produces testosterone or how the body processes consumed food nutrients (I recommend watching [That Sugar Film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3892434/), it tells a lot about such things)

But in any case even on fast food you can gain some muscle, for example, you can get some protein from burgers or steaks etc. But also you will get fat and it could damage your stomach etc, so, thats the reason better stick to the healthy food

Comment: I dont talk about a lot of mounths or years.Small period(1-2 mounths) just to be "visible" a guy with normal body fat or a slim to increase his body fat(as a result muscle will be more visible better body). Yes,it maybe could obtain but which one will be faster for those type of guys to be seemed faster? A guy who eating healthy or the guy whow eats those foods?

Comment: @s.m well, I got such experience - month of unhealthy food, like pizza, burgers etc. so, my abs gone, but strength was ok

Comment: @s.m well if they eat same amount of calories but one eat unhealthy and ohter guy is not - healthy food guy would looks better and probably gain little more, because of no damage for his stomach and stuff